# onDestroy() not called - revisited as all locally stored data needs to be deleted

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

So I love coding as you learn something new every day.  I've been developing Android now for quite a while and always assumed that onDestroy() got called all the time.  Well docs says that it is NOT guarenteed that onDestory() will get called.

So my question is this.  If I have the requirement that no locally saved data exists when the app is closed, how do I go about that.  I code the onDestroy() and when you hit the back button to go to the Android Home Screen sure enough it gets called.

HOWEVER, if I hit the Home button and then tap on the Overview followed by a  Close All / Clear All, the onDestroy() does not get called and I can't ensure that all local data has been deleted?

Comment: There are multiple Android lifecycle components with `onDestroy()`. Which one are you referring to? Application? Activity? Service? Something else?

Comment: As I pointed out in my original note, I need a way to delete local data when the app terminates.  Can't do it with onDestroy as its not guaranteed.  What is when (I guess) the task terminates.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have the requirement that no locally saved data exists when the app is closed, how do I go about that

Do not have locally saved data in the first place. Hold it all in memory.

Comment: Can't.. downloading PDFS and viewing them. Not enough memory to keep it all there so things are written to temp local; however when the app terminates all of this as to be deleted.

Comment: @justdan0227: There is no reliable way of doing that, sorry.

Comment: Really?  Android does not give us a last thing called before it closes the door on an app?

Comment: @justdan0227: Correct. You are supposed to clean things up well before that. Android *may* call `onDestroy()` on running activities and services prior to process termination, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, this is not a clean up, its a no data at termination requirement.

Comment: @justdan0227: Those are equivalent, from a computer programming standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

As pointed in comments you should avoid overriding onStop so i found another way, this method gets called right before onPause (take note of this) when HomeKey is pressed

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    finish();
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

Tested on Android 8.1

NOTE: as docs say it gets called when the user presses the Home key but when you get a call even if the activity calls onPause this method will NOT be called.

Comment: `onStop()` is called in many places having nothing to do with the HOME button.

Comment: That's better, though there can be cases where even that is insufficient. For example, I don't know if `onUserLeaveHint()` is called if the user taps on a different activity in a multi-window environment, and [there are cases where a process can be terminated even though you are in the foreground, in multi-window](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/14/multi-window-permission-revocation.html). This is why I answered "don't save data" -- there are cases where you would not get control as you expect, and I have to assume that the requirement for getting rid of the data needs to be foolproof.

Comment: I agree but if he can't do it in another way i guess this is the only possible solution, as it says here [Activity.class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()) onUserLeaveHint is "Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to go into the background as the result of user choice."

Comment: The only thing is, that I don't want to "clean up" if the app goes in the background, only if its terminated.